# Download files not open it

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to make all files in all types to be download not show it in the browser.

In really I want to make upload files site... all things have done but I have problem with download link... when I want to download file... the browser open it not download it.
I have tried this code in .htaccess:

```
    *FilesMatch "\.(*)$"**
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
**/FilesMatch**
```

and this:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
AddType application/octet-stream .gif
AddType application/octet-stream .jpg
AddType application/octet-stream .jpeg
```

I want help plz.

thanks.

Comment: You can relax the `ForceType application/octet-stream` rule, there's no need to "cast" any type to that MIME type. Apart from that, try adding a `filename` parameter to the `Content-Disposition` header (I can't help you there).

Comment: Can you write full code? @watery

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I do not know the `.htaccess` syntax. I would have written an answer if I knew it :-)